# Mac OS - Auto update DMG

Tags: macos, dmg

I created an application on Mac OS. Now, I need to work with auto-update function.
I try to use Sparkle framework, but it has error when uploading
Do you have any way to do auto-update for an app on Mac OS?

Comment: Before asking new questions it's a good manner to up-vote answers that helped you and moreover accept answers that solved your problems.